# Getting Wepage data same as browser INSPECT option

Tags: python, html

When I go to the following website: https://www.bvl.com.pe/mercado/movimientos-diarios and use Selenium's page_source option, or urllib.request.urlopen what I get is a different string than if I go to Google Chrome, and open the INSPECT option in the contextual menu and copy the entire thing.

From my research, I understand it has to do with Javascript running on the webpage and what I am getting is the base HTML.

What code can I use (Python) to get the same information?

Answer (score 0):

That behavior entirely browser-dependent.  The browser takes the raw HTML, processes it, runs a JS script (usually), styles it with CSS and does many other things.  So to get such a result in Python you'd have to make your own web browser.

Comment: Hmmm... completely outside my expertise. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging around, I came upon a solution that works in most cases. Use Headless Chrome with the --dump-dom switch.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Programmatically in Python use the subprocess module to run Chrome in a shell and either assign the output to a variable or direct the output to a text file.